# Nodejs:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I get the following error anytime i want to access a route.
whenever i access a route it resolves in the following error but the other routes are functioning just this one.

```
/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n')
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:237:46
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17
    at executeCallback (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
    at handleCallback (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:218:62
    at handleCallback (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at completeClose (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:887:14)
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:898:37
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor._endSession (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:193:5)
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor._endSession (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:226:59)
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor.close (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:898:19)
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:218:23
    at handleCallback (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:202:5)
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:560:38
    at /home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:568:46
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor._endSession (/home/sherif/Desktop/fmsD/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:193:5)
```

Please help.

I get the error whenever am accessing a route.

```
router.get('/', [ensureAuthenticated, isAdmin, readAccessControl], async (req, res) => {

    const perPage = 8;
    const page = req.query.page || 1;
    const skip = ((perPage * page) - perPage);

    // const dept = await Department.find();
    const course = await Course.find().skip(skip).limit(perPage);

    if (course) {
        const pages = await Course.find().countDocuments();

        res.render('courses/index', {
            title: 'Courses',
            breadcrumbs: true,
            search_bar: true,
            // dept: dept,
            course: course,
            current: parseInt(page),
            pages: Math.ceil(pages / perPage)
        });
    } else if (dept) {
        res.render('courses/index', {
            title: 'Courses',
            breadcrumbs: true,
            search_bar: true,
            // dept: dept
        });
    } else {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'No department found');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```